# Import a string from a webpack bundle

Tags: typescript, webpack

This works but it's ugly. The required "file" is in a webpack bundle.

```
import "../node_modules/highlight.js/styles/atelier-dune-light.css";
const csspath = "../node_modules/highlight.js/styles/atelier-dune-light.css";
let theCss = require(csspath).default.toString();
console.log(theCss);
```

Yes, I know the import is unnecessary for a direct `require`. I left that in to show the only syntax that doesn't barf.

I strongly suspect that this can all be done directly in the import statement but I can't figure out how to write it.

I eagerly await your `import` fu.

The fact that `require(csspath).default.toString()` works suggests that the default export is some sort of wrapper object. I was hoping to learn how to get the default export object straight into a variable from the import statement, something like this:

```js
import * as swatchCssWrapper from 'highlight.js/styles/atelier-dune-light.css';
```

but that syntax doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For webpack project, you could import like so:**

```
import 'highlight.js/styles/atelier-dune-light.css';
```

**Or relative import like this:**

```
@import '~highlight.js/styles/atelier-dune-light.css';
```

Comment: The short form of the path certainly works (thanks) but it doesn't load it the CSS into a string.